# IF $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then there is $c_y \in (a, b)$ such that $\langle f(b) - f(a), y \rangle = \langle f'(c_y) \cdot(b-a), y\rangle$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be an open set and let $[a, b] \subset U$, $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a map continuous in $[a, b]$, differentiable in $(a, b)$. Show that for each $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists $c_y \in (a, b)$ such that 
>   $$
> \langle f(b) - f(a), y \rangle = \langle f'(c_y) \cdot(b-a), y\rangle.
> $$

It is in the session regarding the Mean-Value Inequality, but I can't see how to use it. Any hints will be the most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint given by @qbert I managed to write the following solution:

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be fixed. Consider the map
$$
\lambda : t \in [0, 1] \mapsto \langle f(a + t(b-a)), y \rangle \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Then we have, by the Mean Value Theorem:
$$
\langle f(b) - f(a), y \rangle = \lambda(1)-\lambda(0) = \lambda'(t_y)(1-0) = \langle f'(a + t_y(b-a))\cdot (b-a), y \rangle. 
$$

Comment: looks fine, you took $c_y=a+t_y(b-a)$ making things a little complicated, but I think it's correct. I would have just applied the mean value theorem to the function I outlined from $[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The problem is that the function you defined has arguments in $\mathbb{R}^m$, thus we don't have a mean value Equality for them. Or am I confused?

Comment: rereading your post, I think there is some confusion. Are you sure $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$? After this you write $[a,b]\subset U$, what does this mean? If it is just an interval in one of the coordinate directions, then you can just compose with some parametrization of that line segment and conclude using the single variable MVT anyway

Comment: Yes, the questions reads $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. In this case $[a, b]$ means the straitght line with endpoints $a$ and $b$. The parametrization is what I did, right? That is why I used you hint but changed it a little.

Comment: yes, looks fine. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the mean value theorem on the function 
$$
x\mapsto \langle f(x),y\rangle
$$